# Sublime Text 2 - plugin

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to use in my plugin search engine that is used by "cmd + p" file search. 
Any clues how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the quick panel in general? As in, you specify a list of entries from your plugin, which are then used to populate the panel. Then the user can search, as they do with the go to anywhere functionality? If so, take a look at the `show_quick_panel` method [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.Window). You essentially specify an array of items (or an array of arrays if you want extra information - such as the path when you do `cmd + p`) and a method to be called on selection or cancel. There are a number of plugins that use this, if you would like a concrete example ([sample 1](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts/blob/master/find_key_conflicts.py#L271), [sample 2](https://github.com/facelessuser/FuzzyFileNav/blob/master/fuzzy_file_nav.py#L465)).

If this isn't what you meant, please clarify.